# Definition of argument in R

Tags: r

If we have something simple like

```html
x <- c(9, 4)

mean(x)
```

Is the variable x itself considered the argument to the function mean()? What is the parameter in this context?

Comment: the parameter is the variable defined in the method/function signature, while the argument is the value/variable passed into the method/function when calling/running it.

Comment: In R everything is an object that you can see in your RStudio Global Environment pane.  So functions act on objects passed as parameters.  In your case x is a vector object.  The Type will be numeric and the length will be 2.  If you pass the wrong type to a function, it will return an error message.  e.g. mean(9) returns 9, mean("9") returns an error.  Here is a link that explains data types in R: https://r-coder.com/data-types-r/  Note that atomic types cannot be mixed in a atomic object.  R will "coerce" them into a single type.

Comment: @SteveM the underlyng question was parameter vs argument and not about data types.

Comment: @Onyambu so we would say that the argument is x because that is the variable being passed into the function mean() when we ran it?

Comment: indeed. The argument is `x` ie whatever you are passing into the function. Unfortunately in this example, the parameter is also `x`. NOT THE `x` defined above, but rather if you look at the signature of the mean function, you would see that it has `x`, or simply if you run `formals(mean)` the first parameter is `x` and then there is `...` which indicates that more parameters can be passed into the function